# Spring JPA Auditing is updating all child entities LastModifiedDate to current date in one to many even if nothing has changed in the child entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa, auditing

I have a Parent entity that has 10 child entities in one to many. While updating parent all the child entitie's LastModifiedDate is getting updated to current date. Is this expected behavior? How does Spring JPA Auditing knows entity has been modified, does it compares field by field?

Comment: Auditing issue has caused due to Mapstruct which is re-intializing the collection arrays while mapping between model and entity.